# Trivial question about orthogonal complement

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $ V = \text{span}\{e_1,e_2,e_3\}$ and $W = \text{span}\{e_1+e_2+e_3\}$.

Then $W^{\bot}$ is given by $\text{span}\{e_1 - e_2, e_1 - e_3\}$. ? ~ from textbook

Why is this? How is a vector in $W^{\bot}$ orthogonal to a vector in $W$?

Suppose $w_1 \in W, w_1 = \begin{bmatrix} e_1+e_2+e_3 \\ 0 \\ 0\end{bmatrix}$ and $w_1 \in W^{\bot}, w_2 = \begin{bmatrix} e_1 - e_2 \\ e_1 -e_3 \\ 0\end{bmatrix}$. Then $w_1 \cdot w_2 = (e_1+e_2+e_3)(e_1 - e_2) + 0 \cdot (e_1 -e_3)  \neq 0.$ What am I missing? =D

Comment: usually $e_1= (1,0,0)^T, e_2 = (0,1,0)^T, e_3 = (0,0,1)^T$

Comment: if $ e_1,e_2,e_3$ are orthogona lvectors then $(e_1+e_2+e_3)(e_1 - e_2) =0$

Comment: but what means $w_1 = \begin{bmatrix} e_1+e_2+e_3 \\ 0 \\ 0\end{bmatrix}$? If $w_1 \in W$ then $w_1=t(e_1+e_2+e_3 )$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using wrong the definition of span. The span is the set of all linear combinations, for example if $w_1\in W$ then $w_1=c(e_1+e_2+e_3)$ with $c$ a constant in your base field. If you think in a concrete example, like $V=\mathbb{R}^3$ and $\lbrace e_1,e_2,e_3\rbrace$ the canonical basis then $w_1\in W$ implies:

$$ w_1=c(e_1+e_2+e_3)=\begin{bmatrix} c \\ c \\ c\end{bmatrix}$$

Hope this help you to understand your mistake and to finish the exercise.

Comment: Ah, I am stupid. Thank you, will accept your answer when I can in 4 minutes. ~ Oskar